# RxJs / Angular: Fetch additional data via subscription inside a map loop

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscription

I'm pretty new to angular and rxjs and I just can't get it solved.
I know my code is wrong, but i don't know how to write it correctly.

I'm fetching a JSON via a HTTP Request, the JSON contains data in an array.
After that i want to loop through the array inside the JSON data and fetch additional data of another HTTP Endpoint.

I looked into flatMap, switchMap, and so on and I can't figure to combine these commands in my case.

Thank you guys!

My Code so far:

```
  checkMatches() {
    this.http.get<{
      message: string,
      result: any}>
    (BACKEND_URL + 'matches')
        .pipe(map((matchData) => {
          return {matches: matchData.result.map(match => {
            this.userService.getUserData(match.matchedUser).subscribe(userData => {
              console.log(userData);
            }
              );
            return {
              id: match._id,
              matchedUser: match.matchedUser,
              firstMatch: match.firstMatch,
              name: userData.userName,
              img: userData.userImg,
              status: match.status,
            };
          })};
        }))
        .subscribe(transformedMatchData => {
        console.log(transformedMatchData);
        });
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you are looping over an array and doing HTTP calls in each loop, can you specify all your requirement in a better way?

Comment: @AshishRanjan That's correct. The first http call gives me a JSON like this: {message: sometext, matches: [{id:xxx, status,:xxx, userId: xxx}]. To complete my data I need the additional data (the username and imageUrl) of the "getUserData" which is also a HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As mentioned in comment below, you should re-think about this architecture, you should have a way to get all these records in one/two requests, not to fire 'N' requests if your loop length is 'N'.*

Answering for the original posted question:

It looks like for every reponse of matches, you need to query APIS, you can use `swicthMap()` along with `forkJoin` here:

Using `switchMap` would merge `(BACKEND_URL + 'matches') say Parent observable` url observable along with next observables we create with its result, and also, it cancels new requests of if `parent observable` emits again.

Using `forkJoin` would make you wait for all the child observables to complete before emitting data.

```
checkMatches() {
    this.http.get<{
    message: string,
    result: any}>
    (BACKEND_URL + 'matches')
        .pipe(switchMap((matchData) => {
            return forkJoin(
                ...matchData.result.map(match => {
                    return this.userService.getUserData(match.matchedUser).pipe(
                        map((userData) => {
                            return {
                                id: match._id,
                                matchedUser: match.matchedUser,
                                firstMatch: match.firstMatch,
                                name: userData.userName,
                                img: userData.userImg,
                                status: match.status,
                            };
                        })
                    )
                })
            )
        }))
        .subscribe(transformedMatchData => {
            console.log(transformedMatchData);
        });
}
```

Comment: I upvoted because you've provided a viable solution but I agree with your comment on his OP - this should be architechted differently so as not to require so many trips over the wire.  Seems like all of this data could be fetched with a single GET.

Comment: @BlairHolmes Yes, that is correct so many requests should not go for a single GET

Comment: @AshishRanjan thank you a lot, this works fine!

Mhh, okay, and maybe i should change the serversided code then, to capture the userdata there.